# Converting time from ASN.1 format while running json_query in Ansible

Tags: ansible, asn.1

I have this playbook to find all certificates from a local folder and check for certificate expiry date. While the playbook works perfectly fine, the time displayed is in ASN.1 format. I want to display the time in human readable format. I am not able to do that while using the json_query. looking for the best solution to include human readable datetime along with file name.

```
 - hosts: localhost
   gather_facts: true
   tasks:
     - name: list cert files
       find:
         paths: ../CertsFolder
         file_type: file
         patterns: "*.cer"
         recurse: yes
       register: find_files
 
     - name: "Test for certificate validity for 90 days"
       openssl_certificate_info:
         path: "{{ item.path }}"
         valid_at:
           point_1: "+90d"
       register: certs_info
       with_items:
         - "{{ find_files.files }}"
 
     - name: Notify via Slack
       slack:
         token: "{{ slack_token }}"
         msg: |
           "Certificate expiry alert for the following certificate(s) : {{ item }} "
         channel: "{{ slack_channel }}"
         domain: "{{ slack_domain }}
         validate_certs: 'false'
       loop:
         - "{{ certs_info.results | json_query(jmesquery) | to_yaml }}"
       vars:
         jmesquery: "[*].{CertificateName: path, Expired: expired, ExpiryDate: not_after }"
       ignore_errors: true
```

Current Output

```
Certificate expiry alert for the following certificate(s) : -{CertificateName: certname.cer, Expired: true, ExpiryDate: 20210223120000Z}
-{CertificateName: Newcertname1.cer, Expired: true, ExpiryDate: 20210123120000Z}
-{CertificateName: webserver.cer, Expired: true, ExpiryDate: 20210325120000Z}
```

Looking to switch the `20210325120000Z` to something like `2021-03-25 12:00:00` or something easily readable

Tried regex_replace as suggested inside jmespath but I get the following error

```
"msg": "JMESPathError in json_query filter plugin:\nBad jmespath expression: Unknown token
```

Comment: You have not included one byte of output, neither the current, nor the expected. Please do have a read over the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) section and edit your question accordingly

Comment: @mdaniel my apologies. updated with output now.

Comment: Does that mean you're not aware of [the `regex_replace` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#searching-strings-with-regular-expressions) or you've tried it and are not experiencing success?

Comment: @mdaniel, i tried with to_date() inside the jmesquery and ansible didnt like it much. i'm not sure how regex_replace will help as there is no specific pattern with to extract within the ASN.1 format.

Comment: lol, wat? `(2021)(03)(25)(12)(00)(00)Z, \1-\2-\3 \4:\5:\6` (TZ silliness aside)

Comment: @mdaniel no i mean, the date and time will keep changing. doing for 1 item is easy.  but lets say i have 10 certs with different expiry date, how are you going to segregate that? can we do something like (:4)(:2) to group first 4 and then 2 & 2?